# Do the "iso-quality" lines meet at the critical point in thermodynamic diagrams?

Tags: thermodynamics

As far as I can tell, this is true in the $h-T$ and $T-s$ diagrams. Is it also true in an $h-s$ diagram, is it true in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Of course it's true in general.  Just go 1 degree below the critical temperature.  They all have to be bunched together there.  What other possibility is there?